# Post operation sync plugin control with ExecuteTransactionrequest

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have a post-operation sync plugin which writes events data into a eventhub. However we have some custom functionality which uses ExecuteTransactionrequest to run batch operations.

If the transactions running under ExecuteTransactionrequest fails it rollsback however data written into eventhub can't be rolled back.

Is there a way to control firing of post-operation plugins with this so that they fire after all the operations are completed.

Comment: Can you reorder the steps to see if the ExecuteTransactionRequest completes before you send the data to the EventHub? Otherwise, if the transaction fails, you may have to send another "cancel" message to the Event Hub.

Comment: At what point can I send a cancel message?

Comment: If you're using the OOB Azure integration, when a transaction fails you could trigger another plugin to send a "cancel" message to the Event Hub. For example: Run ExecuteTransactionRequest, if it fails, update a new "transactionStatus" field with something like "failed", then have a plugin trigger on that, check the transactionStatus message. If it's "failed", send the "cancel" request to the Event Hub.

Answer (score 0):

Your options here are somewhat limited, you could try pre-validation.

[Pipeline stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327941%28v%3Dcrm.8%29#pipeline-stages)

> Pre-validation - Stage in the pipeline for plug-ins that are to
>   execute before the main system operation. Plug-ins registered in this
>   stage **may execute outside the database transaction**. The
>   pre-validation stage occurs prior to security checks being performed
>   to verify the calling or logged on user has the correct permissions to
>   perform the intended operation.
>
> Pre-operation - Stage in the pipeline for plug-ins that are to execute
>   before the main system operation. Plug-ins registered in this stage
>   are executed **within the database transaction**.
>
> Post-operation - Stage in the pipeline for plug-ins which are to
>   execute after the main operation. Plug-ins registered in this stage
>   are executed **within the database transaction**.

[Inclusion in database transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327941%28v%3Dcrm.8%29#inclusion-in-database-transactions)

> Any registered plug-in that executes during the database transaction
>   and that passes an exception back to the platform cancels the core
>   operation. This results in a rollback of the core operation. In
>   addition, any pre-event or post event registered plug-ins that have
>   not yet executed and any workflow that is triggered by the same event
>   that the plug-in was registered for will not execute.

If you are using event hub as some sort of logging, I would advise that you don't, as transaction rollback is likely to wipe out any logs.

You could consider taking your logging outside of CRM. Or, if you have to have it within CRM, then send the data somewhere it can't be rolled back first. For example plugin > external web service > CRM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asynchronous plugin. Asynchronous steps are only invoked when the synchronous plugin pipeline has completed without errors.

Comment: Would the order of messages be maintained in the plugin is asynchronous?

Comment: I am not sure, but I doubt it. Asynchronous tasks are picked up from the asyncoperation table by one or more asynchronous service processes. Tasks are processed in chronological order, but since there are multiple processes executing an exact order cannot be guaranteed I guess.